# jquery change background color of td when clicked on empty portion

Tags: jquery, html-table

I am working on event management project. I created an event in 1 day. I want to change the background color of the `td` only when the user clicks on an empty portion. If they click on the event div there should be no change in background color.

```
$(document).on("click", "td", function() { 
  $(this).css("background-color", "lightblue");
});
```

If I click on the event the background color changes. I want that it only changes when I click on an empty portion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To achieve this you can check that the `event.target` matches the element the event is bound to. Try this:

```js
$(document).on("click", "td", function(e) {
  if (e.target == this)
    $(this).css("background-color", "lightblue");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Click me and the BG will change
      <div>Click me and it won't</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```